# SharePoint Designer Get an Excel Value (REST)

Tags: sharepoint-designer, rest, designer-workflow

I have the following problem: I want to get the values of excel cells with the REST Api and in SharePoint Designer 2013. So to do this I created a workflow with the "Call HTTP web service" action. But now I'm a little bit stuck somewhere:

1. The URL: I've found some REST endpoints for Excel [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff394530.aspx). But I cannot find the endpoint for cell values. :-/
2. I have problems with the request header. To get a better feeling for the Excel Api I just wanted to start by getting the titles of all workbook sheets (with the "`/Model/Sheets?$format=atom`" endpoint).  For this I created the following RequestHeader Dictionary:

[image]

But when logging the ResponseCode to Workflow History List I only get "Forbidden". I thought it was a similar problem like [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/116549/excel-services-rest-api-returns-401-unauthorized-in-workflow) so I added the "Authorization: (empty string)" to the Request Header, but it did not work. :-/

So why is my request forbidden? :-/

Maybe someone can help me with this two little questions o:

Comment: Never used the Excel Services REST API before but by that documentation it looks like you can only reference named ranges.

Answer (score 0):

The REST endpoint for getting the cell value of A1 would be something like this: https://.../sites/testsite/_vti_bin/ExcelRest.aspx/DocLib/test.xlsx/Model/Ranges('Sheet1!a1')

I followed the steps here https://sergeluca.wordpress.com/2013/04/09/calling-the-sharepoint-2013-rest-api-from-a-sharepoint-designer-workflow/ and it worked for me.

Maybe there is a case sensivity problem concerning the request parameters: Content-Type, Accept
For the values of these I used: application/**json**; odata=verbose