# REST excel services

Tags: 2013, javascript, sharepoint-rest-api

I'm following this tutorial [on using Excel Services REST api](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff961897%28v=office.14%29.aspx) and trying to read a range.

If I paste the url into my browser it works and I see the range in my browser.

```
http:<site>/_vti_bin/ExcelRest.aspx/<library>/<file>/Model/Ranges('<range>')
```

But if I use jquery ajax in a content or script editor webpart, it doesn't work. First I get an authorization challenge which doesn't accept my credentials and then if I cancel that, I get a 401 unauthorized error.

```
$.ajax({
    url:exact_same_url_as_above,
    type:"GET",
    headers:{
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "X-RequestDigest":$("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
    }
})
.done(function(data,status,xhr){
    console.log(data);  
})
```

I am the site collection owner and have full control over everything. I have lots of REST api code running in other locations in the site, but this is the first that uses the 2010 `_vti_bin` access point.

Any idea what is going on?

Comment: try changing the get to a post?

Comment: Thanks for the idea. Tried it and got the same result. Usually if it works in the browser bar and/or is a read it is just a GET.

Comment: Are you running the script in a page within http:<site> ?

Comment: Yes. On the same page I used a 2013 REST call (/_api/web/lists('guid')/items(#) to retrieve the title and other information about the document and those worked just fine.

Comment: Have you tried it in fiddler?

Comment: @MickB I'm not sure what that means. I've used the chrome debug tools to check the network traffic and see the headers and authorization error. But there isn't anything in that I understand which sheds light on the reason. What would fiddler get me in this case?

Comment: I think you want different request headers. a fiddler on my excel connection uses these headers: Accept: text/html, text/plain, text/xml and your content type is unlikely to be json too.

Comment: Is this Applies to: SharePoint 2013? Can I use _vti_bin/ExcelRest.aspx in Sharepoint 2013?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using postman to run a few tests.

When I include the headers:

```
    "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
```

I get 401 Unauthorized like you are experiencing. Not even admins can draw blood from a turnip or json from ExcelRest.aspx

Solution:

If I remove the Content-Type entry I get a response back with the data I am looking for.

Getting the data you are looking for:

Use either the $format=ATOM or $format=HTML or $format=image URL parameters to drive the response content type.

Comment: That is so crazy. Seems like that would be a reason to throw an error or something not require an impossible authentication! In any event it works. I removed content-type from the header, added datType:"text" to the props, used $format=json in the url and added JSON.parse(data) in the done handler.

Comment: @Rothrock That was a cryptic comment about `added datType:"text" to the props`. I strongly recommend a solution found there: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/117469/96802. It explains and fixes the 401 error and returns json all right